# Working with cronjobs, bashscripts to automate MySQL backups

Tags: bash, backup, mysql, cron

- I am currently setting up a system which uses a MySQL database.
- I want to create automated backups which run every evening at 10:00PM and also keep the backups for 30 days.

I know there is a way using cronjob and a bashscript which is executed.
I already configured a `.my.cnf` for my SQL user so I won't have to paste the password into the bashscript.

All the tutorials I find do have some extras which I don't need and currently I don't feel to confident to create a script myself.

**Do you have an idea or tutorial which is simple and easy?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really a need for a bash script.
First, work out what backup command would work for you. In principle, you could do something as easy as:

```
mysqldump > /path/to/mysqldump.sql 2>/path/to/mysqldump.err
```

This will write the contents of all the data bases to a file called `mysqldump.sql`. The form of this is such that, if you need to restore the data base after a disaster, all you need to do is `mysql < /path/to/mysqldump.sql`. Moreover, `mysqldump` preserves database integrity, i.e. it will produce a consistent copy of the database even if a transaction was going on at the time of the dump. If there is an error, it will be written to `mysqldump.err`.

You may need to investigate parameters such as `-u`, `--login-path=local` and `--events`. Also you may want to specify certain `--databases` to be backed up. For the sake of this discussion, I will not go into all that.

When the `mysqldump` command works to your satisfaction, you will want to have it run automatically as a cron job. To run the dump at 22:00 daily, specify this in the cron tab:

`0 22 * * * mysqldump ... (etc)`

Of course, this will overwrite the dumped database daily. To keep 30 copies, you will want to use `logrotate`. In `/etc/logrotate.d`, create a new file called (let's say) `mysqldump`. In this file enter this:

```
/path/to/mysqldump.sql {
  su (your username)
  rotate 30
  daily
  missingok
  notifempty
}
```

Save the file and restart logrotate.

Logrotate will visit your mysqldump directory daily and rename the newest one to `mysqldump.sql.1`, the newest-but-one to `mysqldump.sql.2`, and so on. If you have already 30 copies, it will delete the oldest.

As for tutorials, you don't really need one. Just read `man mysqldump`, `man crontab` and `man logrotate`. These are all very well understood tools that will simply work.